# What parts of the C++ standard library (besides containers) might result in memory allocations?

Tags: c++, std

There are some obvious parts of the standard library that do memory allocation on the heap, e.g. `std::string`, `std::vector`, `std::list` and `std::map`. Other parts can sometimes allocate memory a bit "unexpectedly", in a not immediately obvious way, e.g. `std::function`.

What parts of the standard library, besides strings and containers, might result in memory allocation on the heap? I am mostly interested in the non-obvious cases.

Comment: [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition)

Comment: Everything type-erased (like `std::function`) must use dynamic allocation. Algorithms are likely to use allocation. With few exceptions there is basically no guarantee that something _doesn't_ allocate dynamically, but for many things it is obvious that any reasonable implementation wouldn't.

Comment: `std::swap` could allocate, it needs to create a temporary object, but it isn't going to.  Is this more out of curiosity or do you have something in mind and can't allow dynamic allocations?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Mostly out of curiosity. But I also work with a SW where we try to avoid allocation (after an initial startup) to avoid memory fragmentation and costly allocations (it is a real-time system). But the small allocations we are talking about here is really not an issue.

Comment: @NathanOliver "*`std::swap` could allocate*" - only if the type being swapped doesn't support move semantics. Move-based swaps don't need to allocate, only copy-based swaps do.

Answer (score 4):

There is no clean delineation between parts of the C++ standard library that definitely allocate memory and parts of the standard library that definitely do not. There are certain specific cases where the standard outright forbids a type or function from doing dynamic allocations (`optional` and `variant` are explicitly forbidden from using dynamic allocation implementations). There are certain specific cases where the implementation is expected to, if not outright required to, perform dynamic allocations (anything explicitly specified to be able to throw `std::bad_alloc`).

But beyond those cases, you cannot really know. Outside of cases that are explicitly forbidden, you're going to have to rely on quality of implementation for things.

Comment: In general, most things that can allocate either have an overload that takes an allocator, or are allowed to copy data that has internal allocations. `std::stable_partition` is definitely one of several exceptions to this however.